# Use Visual Studio for Blender Python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, external-applications

I'm starting to understand how can scripting make the use of Blender easy. However, I'm accommodated to Visual Studio's *Intellisense* and I don't know the Blender python API so it would be beneficial to use VS for the task. 
Is there a way to do that? If so, how? It doesn't necessarily have to be VS, any SDK would do. This notepad-like scripting inside Blender is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use any external editor. If you only want to edit the code, see this question: [Workflow for developing add-on/script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/workflow-for-developing-add-on-script)

A way to avoid the constant reloading: [Is it possible to run a script from an external editor without reloading the file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-from-an-external-editor-without-reloading-the-fil)

Other things like correct auto-completion and debugging are also possible, but they require additional configuration, which can be somewhat tricky. Visual Studio is not very popular among Blender developers, I recommend PyCharm or PyDev for this kind of advanced stuff because you can find tutorials for them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look into those and mark this answer as best (and bookmark :D)