# Can Blender automatically reload external script files when they are changed?

Tags: python, scripting, workflow

I came across this question:

[Is it possible to run a script from an external editor without reloading the file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-from-an-external-editor-without-reloading-the-fil)

Which also was asked over here in a similair format:

[Workflow for developing add-on/script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/workflow-for-developing-add-on-script)

But the answers over there are over 2 years old. So I assume there must be a better solution by now.

In short, is there? If so, please answer question at "[Workflow for developing add-on/script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/workflow-for-developing-add-on-script)". And refer to that answer in the answer here below. If there is not, please answer as well.

**To rehearse the question.**

*Can Blender automatically reload external script files when they are changed?*

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107291/how-to-reload-all-text-editor-scripts-at-once)  The script in answer could be run modaly or in handler.