# How to reload all text editor scripts at once

Tags: python, scripting

I'm creating some simple scripts to automatize my workflow. Things like:

```
import bpy
# import find_and_close_open_edges

def select_by_pattern(name="SovereignMace",part=None,number=None,partsep="_",numsep="."):

    # Sql NVL
    xstr = lambda s: s or "*"

    # name = "Name_<part>[.partnumber]"
    if name is None:
        pattern = ""
    elif part is None:
        pattern = name
    elif number is None:    
        pattern = name + partsep + part
    else:
        pattern = name + partsep + part + numsep + number

    pattern = pattern + "*"

    # pattern = xstr(name) + xstr(partsep) + \
    # xstr(part) + xstr(numsep) + \
    # xstr(number)

    print("Pattern:",pattern)

    # deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # select all objects by pattern
    bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern=pattern)

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

They grow in number, and they become to be dependent on each other. I use an external editor, so I seldom need to reload one or more script at once and the run them in Blender text editor by ALT-P.
Is there a way to reload all scripts used in Blender text editor at once? (Mind I'm not asking how to do F8 reload... that's unrelated)
Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest convert all scripts into one addon instead (convert all functions into operators, what is probably needed at some point anyway), then press `F8` to reload. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/workflow-for-developing-add-on-script BTW: There is no reason to return `FINISHED` (if it's not an operator), have a look into the templates.

Comment: thanks, it's too early for an addon at present...just looking for a fast tweak...

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/how-to-run-a-python-script-external-to-blender-to-run-bpy-commands-in-blendersp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script who does the job:

```
import bpy

# https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php209369-Synchronizing-text-with-changes-from-outside

def execute():
    """ Check modified external scripts in the scene and update if possible
    """
    ctx = bpy.context.copy()
    #Ensure  context area is not None
    ctx['area'] = ctx['screen'].areas[0]
    for t in bpy.data.texts:
        if t.is_modified and not t.is_in_memory:
            print("  * Warning: Updating external script", t.name)
            # Change current context to contain a TEXT_EDITOR
            oldAreaType = ctx['area'].type
            ctx['area'].type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
            ctx['edit_text'] = t
            bpy.ops.text.resolve_conflict(ctx, resolution='RELOAD')
            #Restore context
            ctx['area'].type = oldAreaType

execute()
```

you can run the script in the text editor or console, and it will reload all scripts which are into text editor and have been modified.