# How solve "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'"?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

in Jupyter notebook i have loaded bpy module :

```
import bpy
```

with no problem. But if i load the 3D view :

```
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

give me this error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**`bpy` as a python module is headless**

There is no ui associated with `bpy` that is compiled as a python module. Objects like `screen` `area` and `region` are part of the UI which being non existent, are given the value `None`.

Comment: if i need to visualize my model that i create with script into jupyter, how do this?
what command i need to use?

Comment: Display how?  As a render, in blender, or otherwise?

Comment: its the same. Visualize like in 3d view in objects or in render mode. For see change of items that i create with script. For see change in real time.

Comment: IMO Not the same, a render is an image, using the 3d viewport involves opening blender, exporting to some other format that has a viewer app is another option.  For using blender, perhaps the suggestion by @rob in your  similar question re setting up a client server and feeding the opened blender your scripts (especially if you want to manipulate the UI) rather than using  the `bpy` module.

Comment: I thinking about a trigger that check, inside blender script , a change from jupyter script. I can i do this? I open a new Ask for this?

Comment: Related to that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-from-an-external-editor-without-reloading-the-fil   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113912/is-automatic-reload-from-disk-confirmation-in-text-editor-possible

Comment: ok. i try this. ty.